# why I have file_get_content warning

Tags: php

I used `file_get_content()` to read from the uploaded image temp file and store in database.
Everything is work fine except this warning. It show every page of my site. And there is no such page  "`footer.php`". Is it the server problem or I need to change that function.

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://admanager.nethosting.com/getads/www.mogoke.5gbfree.com/):
>   failed to open stream: Connection timed out in
>   /usr/share/php/footer.php on line 11

Comment: use [fsockopen()](http://us2.php.net/function.fsockopen) so you can have proper error reporting. `$fp = fsockopen("http://admanager.nethosting.com/getads/www.mogoke.5gbfree.com/", 80, $errno, $errstr, 120);` where `120` is 2 minutes.

Comment: if its not your code the its the free host adding its ads file using auto_append_file ini directive, its not something we can help you with.

Comment: Or, rather, it's your free host *trying* to insert ads, but failing noisily. Either way, get a real hosting provider that doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is *another* invocation of `file_get_contents`, which downloads advertisements from a remote server, but that download fails due to network problems or a firewall.

This looks very much like your code or server had a security vulnerability and someone uploaded code that includes ad banners on your website (but the money for the clicks of course goes to the crooks instead of you). Removing the malware (i.e. the added advertisement lines, probably heavily obfuscated) should suffice. See [this security.stackexchange.com question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39231/1261) for more details.